# How do you resolve a relative Uri?

Tags: android, relative-path, absolute-path

Given an absolute `Uri` and a relative `Uri` or relative path, how do you get the absolute `Uri` pointing to the relative location?

For example, suppose we have the `Uri` for `file:///android_asset/dir`, pointing to a location in our assets. Further suppose that elsewhere, we have a relative path of `/foo`. The absolute `Uri` for that relative path should be `file:///android_asset/foo`. Is there something on `Uri`, or elsewhere in the Android SDK, that I am missing that give me that result `Uri`?

`Uri.withAppendedPath()` is not the answer, as all it seems to do is handle trailing directory separators:

```
Uri abs=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/");
Uri rel=Uri.withAppendedPath(abs, "/foo");
Assert.assertEquals("file:///android_asset/foo", rel.toString());
  // actually returns file:///android_asset//foo

Uri abs2=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/dir");
Uri rel2=Uri.withAppendedPath(abs2, "/foo");
Assert.assertEquals("file:///android_asset/foo", rel2.toString());
  // actually returns file:///android_asset/dir//foo
```

`Uri.Builder`, via `buildUpon()` on `Uri`, is not an improvement:

```
Uri rel3=abs.buildUpon().appendPath("/foo").build();
Assert.assertEquals("file:///android_asset/foo", rel3.toString());
  // actually returns file:///android_asset/%2Ffoo

Uri rel4=abs.buildUpon().appendEncodedPath("/foo").build();
Assert.assertEquals("file:///android_asset/foo", rel4.toString());
// actually returns file:///android_asset//foo
```

In a pinch I can try using `java.net.URL` and its `URL(URL context, String spec)` constructor, or just roll some code for it, but I was hoping to stay in the realm of Android `Uri` values if possible, just for any quirks differentiating `URL` and `Uri`.

Comment: no need to add slash for appendPath - it does it for you. I have my method getBaseUriBuilder to get Uri.Builder with schema+root. So all you need is to append path and query params...

Comment: "So all you need is to append path" -- there are many possible relative path structures. `/foo` is just one. There is also `foo`, `./foo`, `../foo`, `../../foo/bar`, and so on. Many will use part of the path of the absolute `Uri`, others (e.g., `/foo`) will not. I'm trying to handle all the situations, if possible.

Comment: see File construtors: `File(File dir, String name)` and/or `File(String dirPath, String name)` and `File#getCanonicalPath()`

Comment: @pskink: Yes, but not every `Uri` is a `File`. For example, your approach will not work for `http` URLs (port, fragment, query parameters, etc.), `file:///android_asset/` (since a relative `Uri` for it would need to retain the `/android_asset/` part), etc. If you're saying "rip all the extraneous stuff off, use `File` to handle the relative-ness, handle `android_asset` yourself, and then re-assemble all the stuff you ripped off", while that's possible, that's what "just roll some code for it" meant. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, I wouldn't call it a silver bullet, but anything is better than nothing. ;-)

Comment: Why don't you try `Uri rel=Uri.withAppendedPath(abs, "foo");`, then the return will be `file:///android_asset/foo`

Comment: @BNK: As I wrote in a previous comment, there are many possible relative path structures. `/foo` is just one. There is also `foo`, `./foo`, `../foo`, `../../foo/bar`, and so on. Many will use part of the path of the absolute `Uri`, others (e.g., `/foo`) will not. I'm trying to handle all the situations, if possible.

Comment: @CommonsWare how about these lines `URI absolute = new URI("file:////android_asset/");
            URI relative = new URI("foo/bar");
            System.out.println(absolute.resolve(relative));
            // I/System.out﹕ file://android_asset/foo/bar
            relative = new URI("./foo/bar");
            System.out.println(absolute.resolve(relative));
            // I/System.out﹕ file://android_asset/foo/bar
            relative = new URI("../foo");
            System.out.println(absolute.resolve(relative));
            // I/System.out﹕ file://foo`

Comment: @BNK: That last one should result in an error in an Android-aware `Uri` resolution algorithm.

Comment: Yes, it will be OK if the absolute looks like file:////android_asset/abc/xyz, am I right?

Comment: @BNK: Yes. Basically, `android_asset` in `file:///android_asset` is "magic" and has to be treated differently, as if it were the host of a URL. Regular `file:///` values do not have that restriction. The net is that it appears that there isn't something in the SDK for handling this resolution, and I'll be cobbling something together using `URI` and/or `Uri.Builder`.

Answer (score 4):

Android doesn't make this easy.

In my case, I had to take a base url that may or may not have an included path:

`http://www.myurl.com/myapi/`

...and append a REST API method path, like:

`api/where/agencies-with-coverage.json`

...to produce the entire url:

`http://www.myurl.com/myapi/api/where/agencies-with-coverage.json`

Here's how I did it (compiled from various methods within the app - there may be a simpler way of doing this):

```
String baseUrlString = "http://www.myurl.com/myapi/";
String pathString = "api/where/agencies-with-coverage.json";
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.path(pathString);

Uri baseUrl = Uri.parse(baseUrlString);

// Copy partial path (if one exists) from the base URL
Uri.Builder path = new Uri.Builder();
path.encodedPath(baseUrl.getEncodedPath());

// Then, tack on the rest of the REST API method path
path.appendEncodedPath(builder.build().getPath());

// Finally, overwrite builder with the full URL
builder.scheme(baseUrl.getScheme());
builder.encodedAuthority(baseUrl.getEncodedAuthority());
builder.encodedPath(path.build().getEncodedPath());

// Final Uri
Uri finalUri = builder.build();
```

In my case, the Builder classes for the API client code assembled the `path` prior to combining it with the `baseURL`, so that explains the order of things above.

If I've pulled together the above code correctly, it should handle port numbers as well as spaces in the URL string.

I pulled this source code from the [OneBusAway Android app](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android), specifically the [`ObaContext` class](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android/blob/develop/onebusaway-android/src/main/java/org/onebusaway/android/io/ObaContext.java#L89).  Note that this code on Github also handles the additional case where the user typed in a `baseUrl` (`String serverName = Application.get().getCustomApiUrl()` in the above code) that should override the region base URL (`mRegion.getObaBaseUrl()`), and the user-entered URL may not have `http://` in front of it.

The unit tests that pass for the above code on Github, including cases where port numbers and spaces are included in the `baseUrl` and `path`, and the leading/trailing `/` may or may not be included, are [here on Github](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android/blob/develop/onebusaway-android/src/androidTest/java/org/onebusaway/android/io/test/UrlFormatTest.java).  Related issues on Github where I was banging my head on the wall to try and get this all to work - [72](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android/issues/72), [126](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android/issues/126), [132](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android/issues/132).

I haven't tried this with non-HTTP URIs, but I believe it may work more generally.

Comment: And, fixed another typo.

Comment: Technically, this doesn't answer the question. What you're describing is what I called "just roll some code for it" in the question. From this and the comments, I am inferring that there's no simple in-SDK solution that I missed. So, I'll grant you the bounty. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah, this is as close as I could get using native Android classes.  I agree that given the complexity it does fall into the "roll your own" category.  Thanks for the bounty!

Answer (score 1):

There is an equivalent to `urllib.parse.urljoin` (Python) in Android `URI.create(baseUrl).resolve(path)`.

```kotlin
import java.net.URI

URI.create("https://dmn92m25mtw4z.cloudfront.net/helpvids/f3_4/hls_480/480.m3u8")
    .resolve("0.ts")
// output:
// https://dmn92m25mtw4z.cloudfront.net/helpvids/f3_4/hls_480/0.ts
```

**Sean Barbeau** answer returns wrong URL, it's just appending the `0.ts` to the url.

Comment: Thanks, but note that I was referring to `Uri` (the Android-specific class), not `URI` (the `java.net` class). It is possible that they are interchangeable, but I would not assume that without more testing.